# Problem installing gdal with conda

Tags: python, gdal, django

I am on Ubuntu 21.04 with system level gdal 3.0.4 as verified by `gdalinfo --version`. My conda environment was created using the command `conda create -n dev python=3.7`.  I then used pip to install my django project requirements using `pip install -r requirements.txt`.  My requirements include `pygdal==3.0.4.10` which is the correct version for my system install.

The problem occurs when I try and reference gdal.  Here is an example of the problem using a Python shell.

```py
>>> from osgeo import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/josh/work/pj/django_gis_project/src/dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/josh/work/pj/django_gis_project/src/dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/josh/work/pj/django_gis_project/src/dev/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/josh/work/pj/django_gis_project/src/dev/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0
```

Comment: importing gdal directly like that doesn't work, and other answers seem to indicate that `from osgeo import gdal` is the [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67140421/i-cannot-import-gdal-in-python-3-9-4-even-if-ive-installed-it-successfully) way to do it.  

I'll comb through those two links in greater detail, but my first impression was that they might not be quite right for me.  Either way, thank you for looking at this question.

Comment: You're not using conda "properly".  Make a YAML (*.yml) file containing your requirements then create the conda env from that and let conda handle all the dependencies not pip which (apart from pure python packages) can easily mess your conda env up.  https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file

Comment: I had a similar problem. simply install libffi using conda install -c anaconda libffi

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with python-ldap and I've got the same ImportError.
My solution was to set a fixed version of libffi while creating the conda environment.
You could give `conda create -n dev python=3.7 liffi=3.3` a try.
As alternative try to install pygal with `conda install`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when trying to build and install OpenSfM. The repository uses pybind11 to create bindings for C++ packages. What worked for me was to install libffi from my current conda environment.

```
conda install -c anaconda libffi
```